# How do I use file_get_contents to get a gzip'ed page on a remote web server in php?

Tags: php, gzip, file-get-contents

I'm trying to receive a gzip'ed version of a page through file_get_contents in php 5.2.9

I was able to do it using fopen with the following code:

```
    $opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Accept-Encoding: gzip\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
ob_start();
$fp = fopen('http://example.com', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

That works, but I was hoping there was a way I could do it using file_get_contents instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://example.com',false,$context);
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'compress.zlib://http://example.com'

Answer taken from here:
[How can I read GZIP-ed response from Stackoverflow API in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581924/how-can-i-read-gzip-ed-response-from-stackoverflow-api-in-php/8582042#8582042)