# How can I read GZIP-ed response from Stackoverflow API in PHP?

Tags: php, gzip

How can I read a response from Stackoverflow API in PHP? The response is GZIP-ed. I found e.g. the following suggestion:

```
$url = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/" . $question_id;
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = http_inflate($data);
```

but the function `http_inflate()` is not available on the installation that I am using.

Are there some other easy ways to accomplish it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A cool way
http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php

Notice the use of a stream wrapper, *compress.zlib*

```
$url = "compress.zlib://http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/" . $question_id; 
echo $data = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('header'=>"Accept-Encoding: gzip\r\n"))));
```

or using curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
  , CURLOPT_HEADER => 0
  , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
  , CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip'
));
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

edited--
other methods removed because they don't send an `Accept-Encoding` http header.

Comment: This works indeed! I also tried `compress.zlib` before, but did not format the complete url properly. Thanks (+1)!

Comment: easily the best method (stream wrapper)

Comment: @chris: `gzopen()` works as well. Is there a difference in performance between your 3 methods?

Comment: I'm not sure, but my money is on the stream wrapper + file_get_contents

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks goat.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get gzip encoding json response its working like a charm

```
function get_gzip_json($url) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
   CURLOPT_URL => $url,
   CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip',
 ));

 $json = curl_exec($ch);
 $json= mb_convert_encoding($json, "UTF-8", "UTF-8"); 

 return $json;
}
```