# StackOverflow API and PHP CLI and JSON

Tags: php, json, api, command-line-interface, stackexchange-api

I'm new to JSON and APIs and I want to make a PHP CLI script that will use StackOverflow API. I've made myself a key and this is my code so far:

```
<?php

//Call stack API .$key
$google_url = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/stats";

//Get and Store API results into a variable
$result = file_get_contents($google_url);
//$jsonArray = json_decode($result);
print_r($result);
//var_dump($jsonArray);

?>
```

But the `print_r($result);` returns some strange characters.  I can't read it could you give me some info? Any help will be appreciated. The whole project will be an open source search engine about StackOverflow posts and comments!

Comment: You're probably getting the gzip compressed form of the data.  If you use cURL instead of file_get_contents(), you can tweak the options so it handles gzip for you.

Comment: thanks a lot that was the problem indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to un gzip it even if you didn't send an *accept: gzip* header in the http request, because [all responses are gzip'd](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage)

see
[How can I read GZIP-ed response from Stackoverflow API in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581924/how-can-i-read-gzip-ed-response-from-stackoverflow-api-in-php)

Comment: OOOO you rock man thanks a lot! that save my problem! One more question so i want to get a question with it's comments using this API how can i get it and store them on an array!