# file_get_contents equivalent for gzipped files

Tags: php, file, gzip

What would be equivalent function to `file_get_contents`, which reads the whole content of a text file written using `gzwrite` function?

Answer (score 23):

This is way easier using [stream wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php)

```
file_get_contents('compress.zlib://'.$file);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8582042/1235815

Answer (score 2):

It would obviously be [gzread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzread.php) .. or do you mean [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) ?

**Edit:**
If you don't want to have a handle, use [readgzfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readgzfile.php).

Comment: thanks, but file_get_contents takes as an argument the file path, not the handle. gzread uses resource, not paths, so this is not the equivalent.

Comment: `readgzfile` outputs to stdout, not to a string. But using `gzread` worked well for me. E.g. `$zd = gzopen($fname, "r");$gz = gzread($zd, 100 * 1024 * 1024);gzclose($zd);`  (I'm setting a max filesize of 100MB; adjust if that is not enough.)

Answer (score 2):

I tried @Sfisioza's answer, but I had some problems with it.  It also reads the file twice, once and non-compresses and then again as compressed.  Here is a condensed version:

```
public function gz_get_contents($path){
    $file = @gzopen($path, 'rb', false);
    if($file) {
        $data = '';
        while (!gzeof($file)) {
            $data .= gzread($file, 1024);
        }
        gzclose($file);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the compressed data from file_get_contents to gzdecode.

```
$text = gzdecode(file_get_contents("file.txt.gz"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function I was looking for, based on the comments in the manual:

```
/**
 * @param string $path to gzipped file
 * @return string
 */
public function gz_get_contents($path)
{
    // gzread needs the uncompressed file size as a second argument
    // this might be done by reading the last bytes of the file
    $handle = fopen($path, "rb");
    fseek($handle, -4, SEEK_END);
    $buf = fread($handle, 4);
    $unpacked = unpack("V", $buf);
    $uncompressedSize = end($unpacked);
    fclose($handle);

    // read the gzipped content, specifying the exact length
    $handle = gzopen($path, "rb");
    $contents = gzread($handle, $uncompressedSize);
    gzclose($handle);

    return $contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_get_contents("php://filter/zlib.inflate/resource=/path/to/file.gz");
```

I'm not sure how it would handle gz file header.

Comment: This didn't work for me (PHP 5.5.9, Mint 17); I get a 0 byte file.