# Why file_get_contents returning garbled data?

Tags: php, httpresponse, file-get-contents, inflate

I am trying to grab the HTML from the below page using some simple php.

URL: https://kat.cr/usearch/architecture%20category%3Abooks/

My code is:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://kat.cr/usearch/architecture%20category%3Abooks/');
echo $html;
```

where `file_get_contents` works, but returns scrambled data:

[image: scrambled data via PHP file_get_contents()]

I have tried using `cUrl` as well as various functions like: `htmlentities(),` `mb_convert_encoding`, `utf8_encode` and so on, but just get different variations of the scrambled text.

The source of the page says it is `charset=utf-8`, but I am not sure what the problem is.

Calling `file_get_contents()` on the base url `kat.cr` returns the same mess.

What am I missing here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363022/get-url-content-php

Check this out.

Comment: See: [How can I read GZIP-ed response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8581924/55075)

Comment: scrapeing torrent site, thats kind of low

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your site response is being compressed, therefore you've to uncompress in order to convert it to the original form.

The quickest way is to use [`gzinflate()`](http://php.net/gzinflate) as below:

```
$html = gzinflate(substr(file_get_contents("https://kat.cr/usearch/architecture%20category%3Abooks/"), 10, -8));
```

Or for more advanced solution, please consider the following function (found at this [blog](http://www.binarytides.com/php-fetch-gzipped-content-over-http-with-file_get_contents/)):

```
function get_url($url)
{
    //user agent is very necessary, otherwise some websites like google.com wont give zipped content
    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8rn" .
                        "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdchrn" .
                        "Accept-Charset:UTF-8,*;q=0.5rn" .
                        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.4rn"
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $content = file_get_contents($url ,false,$context); 

    //If http response header mentions that content is gzipped, then uncompress it
    foreach($http_response_header as $c => $h)
    {
        if(stristr($h, 'content-encoding') and stristr($h, 'gzip'))
        {
            //Now lets uncompress the compressed data
            $content = gzinflate( substr($content,10,-8) );
        }
    }

    return $content;
}

echo get_url('http://www.google.com/');
```

Answer (score 3):

It is GZ compressed and when fetched by the browser the browser decompresses this, so you need to decompress.  To output it as well you can use [readgzfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readgzfile.php):

```
readgzfile('https://kat.cr/usearch/architecture%20category%3Abooks/');
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple and effective.