# PHP file_get_contents Returning Inconsistent Partial Data for HTTP Requests

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am attempting to use PHP SoapClient to execute requests to a third-party application.  When I create the SoapClient object I get an error about premature end of data for the WSDL.  In trying to diagnose the error I found that file_get_contents() for the WSDL URI does not return the entire XML.  In fact, it frequently returns different amounts of the WSDL.  Here is my test program:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('https://webservices3.autotask.net/atservices/1.6/atws.wsdl');
echo $xml . "\n";
echo strlen($xml). "\n";
```

I get around 57k bytes each time (195628 is the correct value), sometimes more and very rarely I get the entire XML.  I believe this is a PHP issue because a shell loop to call curl or wget 100 times each for this URI will 100% of the time return the entire file.  I am on PHP 5.4.16 which I know is old (2013), but this process was working for about a month and then just stopped entirely.

I've tried changing timeouts, HTTP protocol versions, PHP memory settings, but I can't figure out why file_get_contents would behave this way.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Curl test:

```
for a in $( seq 1 100 ); do curl -o wsdl.$a https://webservices3.autotask.net/atservices/1.6/atws.wsdl; done
```

Wget test:

```
for a in $( seq 1 100 ); do wget -O wsdl.$a https://webservices3.autotask.net/atservices/1.6/atws.wsdl; done
```

Update 1:

Setting maxlen to some stupid large number does not affect the behavior:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('https://webservices3.autotask.net/atservices/1.6/atws.wsdl', false, null, 0, 999999);
echo $xml . "\n";
echo strlen($xml). "\n";
```

Update 2:

```
$ curl -s -D /dev/stderr -- https://webservices3.autotask.net/atservices/1.6/atws.wsdl > /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 14:38:25 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "39163cd7331ed61:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https: *;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: *;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';img-src 'self' https://walkme.psa.datto.com/Images/ data: https://www.datto.com/img/
Date: Fri, 08 May 2020 15:22:28 GMT
Content-Length: 195628
```

Here are the response headers as PHP reports them:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('https://webservices3.autotask.net/atservices/1.6/atws.wsdl');
echo $xml . "\n";
echo strlen($xml). "\n";
echo var_dump($http_response_header);

array(11) {
  [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  [1]=> string(22) "Content-Type: text/xml"
  [2]=> string(44) "Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 14:38:25 GMT"
  [3]=> string(20) "Accept-Ranges: bytes"
  [4]=> string(25) "ETag: "39163cd7331ed61:0""
  [5]=> string(25) "Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5"
  [6]=> string(21) "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET"
  [7]=> string(228) "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https: *;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: *;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';img-src 'self' https://walkme.psa.datto.com/Images/ data: https://www.datto.com/img/ "
  [8]=> string(35) "Date: Fri, 08 May 2020 15:26:54 GMT"
  [9]=> string(22) "Connection: keep-alive"
  [10]=> string(22) "Content-Length: 195628"
}
```

Update 3:

Corrupt Content-Length header from PHP with gzip:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Accept-Encoding: gzip\r\n"
     )
));
$xml = file_get_contents('https://webservices3.autotask.net/atservices/1.6/atws.wsdl', false, $ctx);
echo var_dump($http_response_header);

array(12) {
  [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  [1]=> string(22) "Content-Type: text/xml"
  [2]=> string(44) "Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 14:35:51 GMT"
  [3]=> string(20) "Accept-Ranges: bytes"
  [4]=> string(24) "ETag: "b376e7b331ed61:0""
  [5]=> string(25) "Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5"
  [6]=> string(21) "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET"
  [7]=> string(228) "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https: *;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: *;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';img-src 'self' https://walkme.psa.datto.com/Images/ data: https://www.datto.com/img/ "
  [8]=> string(35) "Date: Fri, 08 May 2020 15:44:12 GMT"
  [9]=> string(22) "Connection: keep-alive"
  [10]=> string(22) "ntCoent-Length: 195628"
  [11]=> string(22) "Content-Encoding: gzip"
```

}

Update 4:

Headers from curl with gzip (note they look correct):

```
$ curl --compressed -s -D /dev/stderr -- https://webservices3.autotask.net/atservices/1.6/atws.wsdl > /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 14:35:51 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "807d37b331ed61:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https: *;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: *;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';img-src 'self' https://walkme.psa.datto.com/Images/ data: https://www.datto.com/img/
Date: Fri, 08 May 2020 16:12:13 GMT
Content-Length: 13192
```

I was able to force SoapClient to not use gzip and this did resolve the issue albeit inefficiently.  We still don't have a root cause for PHP mangling the headers.

```
// Autotask Client options
$auth_opts = array(
    'login'    => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'trace'    => 1,
    'http'     => array(
        'header' => array(
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'identity' // here be dragons
        )
    )
);
```

Update 5:

We confirmed this is still reproducible in PHP 7.2.  I have opened a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79575) with the PHP team.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php Try to play with `maxlen` param

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but according to the documentation that is not required and PHP should return the entire file.  I have updated my question to show that setting maxlen does not affect the behavior.

Comment: Kevin, you said "_this process was working for about a month and then just stopped entirely._" . When it happened?.. `Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 14:35:51 GMT`. Maybe it's a proxy? Try to add some get params to url `file_get_contents('https://webservices3.autotask.net/atservices/1.6/atws.wsdl'.'?t='.time());`

Comment: Hard to say: the action is initiated by a user so we might make the request several times in a day or none for a few days.  The first failure I see is on May 4th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in PHP.  There is an [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79575) report linked at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

webservices3.autotask.net has bad header in response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Cteonnt-Length: 195628
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Note: `Cteonnt-Length: 195628` should be `Content-Length: 195628`

That why `file_get_contents` cannot handle request correctly.

So, fix response or set `maxlen`

*UPD:*
It's jumbled header. 
This should works https://stackoverflow.com/a/8582042/3849743

Comment: The headers look okay to me.  I will add them into the question.

Comment: Well, could you provide headers output please?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I was fighting with hitting enter to add a blank line and the comment max length :-)

Comment: Oh, I see. User browser > developer tools > network to verify headers

Comment: Yup, I didn't mention, but I had already validated the headers.  I posted two options for validating that show they are healthy looking.

Comment: Me too (update 3), requesting w/ gzip certainly jumbles the Content-Length header.  Is this a PHP problem or a problem on the server side?

Comment: @KevinSeymour It's PHP issue

Comment: I'm going to blame old PHP.  I was able to disable compression for SoapClient to get around the issue and we'll just live like that for now.  I've accepted this as the answer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KevinSeymour no, I was wrong. file_get_contents is php issue only. Please re-open question and wait a bit for correct answer.

Comment: I have re-opened the question.  I confirmed this is still broken in PHP 7.2.29.

Comment: I updated the question and added a link to the PHP bug I opened.