# ignore source filetype encoding of file_get_contents and/or convert to json encoding

Tags: php, json, character-encoding, file-get-contents

When I load http://www.nydailynews.com/json/cmlink/NYDN.Local.Article.rss in my browser it loads the JSON content just fine. But when pulling the contents with `file_get_contents` I get weird characters like

> ��Y�r��}OU�aV�@

I've tried `$contents = mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents('http://www.nydailynews.com/cmlink/NYDN.Local.Article.rss'), 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");` but that only returns a XML type format, not the JSON viewable in the browser.

UPDATE:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.nydailynews.com/json/cmlink/NYDN.Local.Article.rss');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: The URL you posted is an RSS which is an XML application. There is no JSON involved here.

Comment: My apologies... the source url I am trying to pull from is http://www.nydailynews.com/json/cmlink/NYDN.Local.Article.rss not http://www.nydailynews.com/cmlink/NYDN.Local.Article.rss ... fixing that above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this : 
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.nydailynews.com/cmlink/NYDN.Local.Article.rss'); print_r(gzdecode($contents));

you can see this post for more informations : [why file_get_contents returning strange characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634139/why-file-get-contents-returning-strange-characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert encoding to utf-8 using `DOMDocument`

```
$contents= file_get_contents("http://www.nydailynews.com/cmlink/NYDN.Local.Article.rss");     
$dom = new DOMDocument();    
if($dom->loadXML($contents)){ // $contents is an XML document with iso-8859-1 encoding specified in the declaration
   $dom->encoding = 'utf-8'; // convert document encoding to UTF8
   return $dom->saveXML(); // return valid, utf8-encoded XML
}
```