# 'file_get_contents' The contents are encrypted?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

The problem is when i  use **file_get_contents** to get source (HTML) from this site, the result that i receive is NOT a plain html code.

**The code i used:**

```
$source = file_get_contents("http://mp3.zing.vn/bai-hat/Dance-With-My-Father-Luther-Vandross/ZWZ9D6FD.html");
echo $source;
// OR print_r($source);
```

**The source i received:**

```
��}{�#Ǒ��-��!E��=��Mv�5�B���R�����h��E�HV7YE�������a�X��p{��[�:�!{��;,v��u��Or��̬��Y��M��ʌ̌�����������F��ޖ����ػ��S� #�~��H�7k�����ʎȦ2���M?�ު&D�����t���$u�O��N���>%(Y����I��Vb�[���VN�=�[�![*�dE*�]3:�ޑ�xiA���Z��g ��祇VejI �R�y�֨�ea��o��s�M/�... *MORE
```

**I tried with cURL**, but i also received the same result:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mp3.zing.vn/bai-hat/Dance-With-My-Father-Luther-Vandross/ZWZ9D6FD.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$source = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I think the source i received must have been encrypted, but if i use browser to view source, the source will NOT be encrypted.

**Eventually**, i dont really know ***what happened***, and ***how to get the plain source*** (plain HTML) ?

Comment: Likely not "encrypted", but *compressed*. Encrypted HTML makes no sense, since it's of no use to anyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use file\_get\_contents to get a gzip'ed page on a remote web server in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800147/how-do-i-use-file-get-contents-to-get-a-gziped-page-on-a-remote-web-server-in-p)

Comment: Thank you. I dont really know it's gzip :)

Answer (score 4):

It's gzip compressed, just set the correct encoding and you're good to go

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mp3.zing.vn/bai-hat/Dance-With-My-Father-Luther-Vandross/ZWZ9D6FD.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
$source = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont really know it's gzip :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`gzdecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) (requires the ZLIB PHP module, though - if you don't have it, I'd strongly consider to use JimL's method using cURL).

> string gzdecode ( string $data [, int $length ] )

```
$source = file_get_contents("http://mp3.zing.vn/bai-hat/Dance-With-My-Father-Luther-andross/ZWZ9D6FD.html");
echo gzdecode($source);
// OR print_r($source);
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont really know it's gzip :)