# PHP Curl but the HTML is Encrypted and SSL Certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: html-parsing, simple-html-dom, php-curl

I want to parse the HTML from [this site](https://inaproc.lkpp.go.id/v3/daftar_lpse), I already try to use :

1. [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
2. [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

but the result is awful like this :

[image]

then I try PHP CURL by using [php html parser](https://packagist.org/packages/paquettg/php-html-parser), I found the error is **SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

After searching the answer, then I read [using curl to access https](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/), and I try to get the certificate by using the step in that article **but the result is same**

the question is, why the parsing result is like that? now, I don't know what to do :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page is compressed with gzip.

```
curl -k --compressed https://inaproc.lkpp.go.id/v3/daftar_lpse
```

For PHP

```
$ch = curl_init("https://inaproc.lkpp.go.id/v3/daftar_lpse");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Comment: ahh, I've been wondering if the site is compressed with gzip after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398510/file-get-contents-the-contents-are-encrypted).. I already try to set encoding with gzip according to that, but I don't know the point is to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");` to blank..

huh, my bad, very thanks to you :)

Comment: I expirienced same issue with xBTCe public API. Thanks a lot